# Android Toolbar pulls down - Navigation component

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to transition an app that I have previously made to use Navigation component with fragments instead of activities ( so I'm converting my activities to fragments so they work with the component and also because it's nicer this way) and I have a problem with the `Toolbar` always getting pulled down a little bit without any aparent reason. I tried changing the layout roots from `LinearLayout` to `ConstraintLayout`, back again, fidgeting with `android:fitsSystemWindows` both for the activity layout and for the fragment one as `true` or `false`, also with views `layout_height` but no luck so far...

The activity looks like this:
[image]

here are my files:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    private val baseAppState by inject<BaseAppStateManager>()
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.myNavHostFragment) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
        
    }
    
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
        return navController.navigateUp()
    }
    
}
```

fragment_devices.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_status"
        layout="@layout/dashboard_phone_status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/devices_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

DevicesFragment.kt

```
class DevicesFragment : Fragment() {
    
    ...
    
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, sis: Bundle?): View {
        binding = FragmentDevicesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        phoneStatusScreen = PhoneStatusScreenManager(binding.dashboardStatus)
        return binding.root
    }
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        observeLiveData()
        
        ...viewmodel calls...
    
        historyAdapter = DevicesHistoryAdapter(onDeviceClicked = ::onDeviceClicked)
        setupRecyclerView(historyAdapter)
    }
```

Sometimes the toolbar looks okay when I open the app but as soon as I navigate to another fragment by clicking on an element from the RecyclerView, when I click on the back arrow to navigate up, the toolbar is like you see in the screenshot below.

Also, here is the application theme:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Theme customization. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```